# How to scale my x-axis to log10 in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to scale my x axis to log 10 so that there isnt such a huge stretch at the beginning of the plot,  but the confidence intervals on my plot go below zero so I get this error:

```
Error in if (zero_range(range)) zero_width else diff(range) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In trans$transform(limits) : NaNs produced
```

Is there a way around this so I can still scale my axis or must I stick with it as it is now?

I'm using a continuous x scale right now but I want to change to log 10, here is my plot code:

```
ggplot(drc_2, aes(x= Treatment.concentration.0, y = Total.dead), breaks = drc_2$Treatment.concentration) +
  geom_point(position = position_jitter(width = 0, height = 0.15)) +
  geom_ribbon(data=datanew, aes(x=Treatment.concentration, y = p, ymin=pmin, ymax=pmax), alpha=0.2) +
  geom_line(data=datanew, aes(x=Treatment.concentration, y = p)) +
  coord_trans(x="log") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = drc_2$Treatment.concentration) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 0:5)+
  theme_grey() + theme(axis.title = element_text(face = "bold"),
    plot.title = element_text(face = "bold",
        hjust = 0.5)) +labs(title = "Dose-Response Curve",
    x = "Treatment Concentration (mg/kg)",
    y = "Total Dead")
```

[image]

Comment: A likely solution would be [`psuedo_log_trans`](https://scales.r-lib.org/reference/log_trans.html) from `scales` package. Though without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it's tricky to answer how to use this for your data.

Comment: There are good ways to estimate CIs for dose-response curves that don't go below zero. I'd recommend you use `stat_sum()` rather than `geom_point(..., jitter = ...)` to distinguish overlapping points ...

Comment: use `"log10"` as your transformation function instead of just `"log"`

Comment: Have you tried using scale_x_log10()? Then you could drop the coord_trans line